# Is there any Java equivalent of NumPy?

Tags: java, python, numpy, tensorflow

I tried to get predictions from tflite model to get eye region landmarks.
I successfully got values from tflite model using python script but I didn't know how can I got those values using MLKit firebase.
Python script used numpy library for converting image to arrays.
I want to know what is the problem here?
There is any way to use numpy functions with java code?
If not, what is the equivalent of the numpy library in java?

Python script

```py
data = np.asarray( img, dtype="float32" ) 

# Inference on input data normalized to [0, 1]
inputImg = np.expand_dims(data,0).astype(np.float32)
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], inputImg)

interpreter.invoke()

output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
output_data = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])
print(output_data)
```

Java code ( Android ) the problem is with those functions:

```java
private float[][][][] bitmapToInputArray() {
        // [START mlkit_bitmap_input]
        Bitmap bitmap= getYourInputImage();
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 112, 112, true);

        int batchNum = 0;
        float[][][][] input = new float[1][112][112][3];
        for (int x = 0; x < 112; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 112; y++) {
                int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel) - 127) / 128.0f;
                Log.i("Input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y]);

            }
        }
        // [END mlkit_bitmap_input]

      return input;
    }

 private void useInferenceResult(float[] probabilities) throws IOException {
        String[] result=new String[80];
        String x="";
        String y="";
        ArrayList<Point> listpoint= new ArrayList<Point>();

        double viewWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        double viewHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        double imageWidth = mutableBitmap.getWidth();
        double imageHeight = mutableBitmap.getHeight();
        Log.i("viewWidth","viewwidth "+viewWidth);
        Log.i("viewHeight","viewheight "+viewHeight);
        Log.i("imagewidth","imagewidth "+imageWidth);
        Log.i("imaageHeigh","imageheigh "+imageHeight);
        double scale = Math.min(viewWidth / imageWidth, viewHeight / imageHeight);
        Log.i("Scale","Scale"+scale);
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {

                Log.i("MLKit", String.format("%1.8f", probabilities[i]));
                float i1 = probabilities[i];
                Log.i("floaaat", "" + i1);
            }
        }
```

- The result from the python script:

> [0.33135968 0.19592011 0.34212315 0.17297666 0.36624995 0.16413747
>    0.3894139  0.17440952 0.39828074 0.1978043  0.3891497  0.22268474
>    0.36345637 0.22974193 0.3401759  0.2193309  0.30167252 0.20411113
>    0.3167112  0.19134495 0.33793524 0.18388326 0.3642417  0.18049955
>    0.3903508  0.18533507 0.40906873 0.1957745  0.42142123 0.21091096
>    0.40550107 0.21829814 0.38345626 0.22071144 0.35900232 0.22142673
>    0.3363348  0.21877256 0.3161971  0.2133534  0.62843406 0.21482795
>    0.6389724  0.1914106  0.6628249  0.1835615  0.6858679  0.19583184
>    0.6946868  0.22111627 0.6840309  0.24444285 0.66027373 0.25241333
>    0.6351568  0.24192403 0.60499936 0.22642238 0.6210091  0.21289764
>    0.6423563  0.2042976  0.6685919  0.20277795 0.69201195 0.20948553
>    0.70882106 0.22015369 0.71931773 0.23518339 0.7076659  0.24166131
>    0.69054717 0.24350837 0.6694564  0.24258481 0.64537776 0.23927754
>    0.62199306 0.23511863]

- The result from the Android java code:

> 2019-08-17 14:47:50.617 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,23961355
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.620 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,25104424
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.621 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,28179651
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.622 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,31467810
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.623 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,33257431
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.624 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,32645294
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.625 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,29138848
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.626 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,25581932
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.627 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,19593856
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.628 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,21698779
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.631 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,24266151
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.632 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,27562365
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.633 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,30823168
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.635 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,33465266
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.636 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,35355449
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.637 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,34009647
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.638 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,31358159
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.640 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,28156102
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.642 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,25063315
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.643 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,21878451
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.644 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,69623101
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.646 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,70167470
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.646 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,73317540
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.648 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,76974392
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.649 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,79195201
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.651 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,78359401
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.652 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,75674009
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.653 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,71786618
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.654 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,66782737
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.655 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,68930006
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.656 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,71668541
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.657 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,75279719
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.658 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,78872705
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.659 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,81867975
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.661 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,83806717
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.662 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,82371044
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.664 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,79749656
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.665 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,76317006
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.666 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,72700304
>   2019-08-17 14:47:50.667 21349-21349/com.example.irisdetection I/MLKit: 0,69159627

Comment: How about [nd4j](https://deeplearning4j.konduit.ai/nd4j/overview)? It is part of deeplearning4j, a Java framework for deep learning.

Comment: There is actually an initiative starting to provide a standard API replicating pretty much what NumPy can do in Java, many parties involved in it have already implemented a similar library of their own (DL4J, DJL, TensorFlow...)

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the order of colors from RGB to BRG helped. If you are getting image with cv2.imread then it will be BGR and in 8bit color palette (256 colors for pixel). So you are doing almost right, just change the order

Comment: Thank you, the question is old and I have changed my work to ios using CoreML library,